# Appium: chromeOptions not recognized by appium

Tags: java, automation, appium-android, chrome-options

I am trying to automate a mobile application. In the capabilities.json file, I have included chromeOptions.

```
"goog:chromeOptions": {
      "args": "--disable-fre"
    }
```

I am doing this to skip the Welcome to chrome page during automation. But this does not seem to work as I still keep getting the welcome page.

I got the following in my termial while running the tests.

```
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "goog:chromeOptions": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]       "args": "--disable-fre",
[debug] [BaseDriver]       "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome"
[debug] [BaseDriver]     },
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout": 60000,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "...",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:chromedriverExecutable": "/Users/.../.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/mac64/69/chromedriver",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:fullReset": true,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:noReset": false,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:noSign": true,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "8.0",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:systemPort": 63463,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "emulator-5556"
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   goog:chromeOptions
```

Here, it says that the goog:chromeOptions is not recognised by appium. What do I do to resolve this? I want the welcome screen to be disabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here actually the argument you have used is not a valid one for chromedriver for appium.
Try once without using `--disable-fre`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).